# How to determine if WebSphere MQ installed is 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: ibm-mq

Can you tell me how to identify the version bit of installed IBM WebSphere MQ, 32 or 64? On Windows, Linux and UNIX respectively.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dspmqver -a` like so:

```
bash-3.2$ dspmqver -a
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.0.1.4
CMVC level:  p701-104-110114
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 2.6.18-194.17.4.el5
bash-3.2$
```

Or on Windows:

```
C:\>dspmqver
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.5.0.0
Level:       p000-L120604
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Windows
Mode:        32-bit
O/S:         Windows 7 Ultimate x64 Edition, Build 7601: SP1
InstName:    WMQ75
InstDesc:
InstPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
DataPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
Primary:     Yes
MaxCmdLevel: 750

C:\>
```

Here is the `dspmqver` Infocenter page for [V7.1](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa15760_.htm) and [V7.5](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa15760_.htm).

Answer (score 1):

```
dspmqver -f 96
```

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.doc%2Ffa15760_.htm

Comment: Of the four curent versions, of WMQ, V6 is end-of-life as of September.  Here's a link to the same page in the current V7.5 Infocenter: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa15760_.htm